# Python : Some of Intellisense dosen't work on VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, openpyxl, intellisense

I had some trouble while using openpyxl on the VS code.
Almost of intellisense are work well, but Some of them are not work.
I think intellisenses is not working that some of after dot sentences.

for example // `worksheet = workbook.active` when i wrote this code,the intellisense suggest well`.active`.

but it's not working when i want to write `worksheet.iter_cols` or `.max_row` or `.value` .

I had installed pylance and also got setting Language server.And I use only one version of python 3.9.1 64-bit and openpyxl 3.0.7 version.

It's not critical inconvenience but i want to know how can i fix it. what should i do?

Comment: Since the "Intellisense" function of python code in VS Code is provided by the "Python" extension, please try to reinstall this extension and reload VS Code.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Jill Cheng. I did that when after I read your comment, But unfortunately It didn't  work.
I deleted  "Code" folder in AppData/Roaming folder and  ".vscode" folder. After that I did reinstall the VS Code and another extensions but nothing changed.
Am I miss something?

Comment: -When you enter "_worksheet = workbook._" in VS Code, does it show the "active" option? Could you please provide us with a code snippet that can reproduce this problem?

Comment: I don't know am I correct to understand your comment, Anyway the answer is No. I can't see the any active options. when I type the "worksheet" and "workbook". Just Intellisense only work when I typed `ws = xl.Workbook()` Intellisense recommend 'Workbook' (for reference I imported openpyxl as xl).
If my comment is not enough, Please tell me the information what you need.
I really appreciate your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I use the code "`from openpyxl import workbook`" and the language service used is "Pylance", input "workbook." will display "Intellisense":

[image]

In VS Code, its "Intellisense" will display the methods or classes contained in the imported module, for example: you could click "Ctrl" and click the code "`openpyxl`" or "`xl`" with the mouse, it will jump to the module related definition document:

[image]

And click on the related definition file of "workbook", it has no methods or classes of "iter_cols", "max_row", "value":

[image]

Comment: Ah, It's mean the workbook doesn't contain like `.iter_cols` and `.max_row`?
Thanks, I understand this problem. I learning Python in Youtube now.  And In the Youtuber's intelisense was recommending what I said before. So I had want to know why